# Symfony2.7 : Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony

I want to add an activity in the Database. Yet each time I try I got the following error:

" Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable "

I'm working with 
 symfony version 2.7, 
 php version 7.2.10 and
 PostgreSQL version 4.10

This error did not appear on a lower version of Postgresql and PHP (as I have another setup with the same project running), yet I need it to work on this environment as well. I think the higher version might be the reason for this error without being sure.

In the same time, I've run some test on the controller, when I submit the form it does not even reach the part where I persist and flush the activite object.

FicheController.php

```
public function declarationActiviteAction(Request $req)
{

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $query = $em->getRepository('BundleName:Activite')->findAll();
    $user = $em->getRepository('BundleName:FosUser')->find(1);

    $act = new Activite();
    $form = $this->createForm(new activiteType, $act);
    $form->handleRequest($req);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $em->persist($act);
        $em->flush();
        return $this->redirectToRoute('declaration_activite');
    }
    return $this->render('BundleName:Vues:declaration.html.twig', [
        'table' => $query,
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ]);
}
```

I'm on this for quite a while and don't see how to get out of it, thanks for your help.

Comment: In the provided source code there is no `count`. Can u give a hint in which line the error occurs, preferably a stacktrace?

Comment: This is [added by php 7.2](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration72.incompatible.php#migration72.incompatible.warn-on-non-countable-types). You'll probably have to update your dependencies. UPDATE: Looks like you are hitting [this bug](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/26291)

Answer (score -2):

In case anyone ends up in the same situation

the reply from msg was the correct one.
The issue came from php 7.2.0 as Symfony2.7 is no longer maintained things got messed up. 
The solution is either go back to PHP7.0 or lower or update symfony to 3.4

Comment: Since it was an LTS release, Symfony 2.8 was supported until November 2018 and is still recieving security fixes. Have you tried updating to that first?

Comment: I must stay to version 2.7 for this project so I did not search in depth whether or not 2.8 might solve the issue.

Comment: 2.8 should be fully backwards compatible. But if you have that strict requirement, it is what it is.